# Add file to set screen size on Xorg

Tags: xorg, chromebook, dpi

I recently installed Ubuntu on my new Chromebook Pixel and I'm trying to get the resolution right. Here are the instructions I have received:

> Option #4 set screen size on Xorg so that dpi goes up to 240
>
> Add a file /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/90-monitor.conf to explicitly set the
>   screen size, i.e. containing
>
> Section "Monitor"
>       Identifier             ""
>       DisplaySize            270 180    # In millimeters EndSection These numbers are actually taken from the Xorg log file in /var/log --
>   no clear to me why the correct numbers don't end up being used. Not
>   all apps handle this correctly
>   Option #4 set screen size on Xorg so that dpi goes up to 240
>
> Add a file /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/90-monitor.conf to explicitly set the
>   screen size, i.e. containing
>
> Section "Monitor"
>       Identifier             ""
>       DisplaySize            270 180    # In millimeters EndSection These numbers are actually taken from the Xorg log file in /var/log --
>   no clear to me why the correct numbers don't end up being used. Not
>   all apps handle this correctly

My question is, how do I "add a file?"

Answer (score 0):

I have put a file called resolution.conf in /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d to set the resolution. Put the resolution of choice in front. This works very well in virtual machines so should work on your box. The code is as follows:

```
Section "Screen"
   Identifier      "Default Screen"
   Device          "geforce256"
   Monitor         "S/M 950p"
   DefaultDepth    24
   SubSection "Display"
           Depth           16
           Modes           "1440x900" "1600x1200" "1024x768" "640x480"
   EndSubSection
   SubSection "Display"
           Depth           24
           Modes           "1440x900" "1600x1200" "1024x768" "640x480"
   EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Create the file in e.g. /home/username/file_of_choice.
Now open a terminal and go into the directory: `cd /home/username/file_of_choice` after this copy the file to /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d `sudo cp resolution.conf /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d` you will be asked for your password.

Reboot and the chosen resolution should work.

Make sure you choose a resolution that your screen can handle otherwise you will have no easy way to correct the mistake.

PS) If you only want to add a file (after you made it) use the last part of my instruction, or open Nautilus by typing in terminal:`gksu nautilus` (from Ubuntu 13.04 and up `pkexec nautilus` if I'm correct) and create the file directly in the right directory.